# How to make a variable length sound in Android

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to make an app that plays a sound like a piano organ.  When the user presses a button it will play a piano-like sound.  The difficulty is that the user could hold their finger down for any length of time.  When they lift their finger off the should fade rather than stop abruptly.

I've played with SoundPool and Media Player but they don't seem suitable.

There are a lot of piano apps out there... does anyone know how they solve this problem?

Comment: You might want to look into implementing [some sort of envelope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthesizer#ADSR_envelope) in software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the AudioTrack class. The basic usage is to write your sound data using AudioTrack's `write()` method for whatever duration that you want it to be heard. You'll need to use a separate thread for each simultaneous voice that you want to "play".

Here's the [AudioTrack reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) and here's [a blog entry](http://www.martinhoeller.net/2012/01/13/developing-a-musical-instrument-app-for-android/) where the author does a nice job of showing what to do without a lot of distractions.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at the code in the piano.zip file and the buttons do play variable lengths.